# Filter library view with ParameterBinding in ModernUI

Tags: 2016, view, modern-experience, parameter

I have a custom view with ParameterBinding to get URL a parameter:

```
<ParameterBinding Name="MyCustomParameter" Location="QueryString(MyCustomParameter)" DefaultValue=""/>
```

The view CAML query:

```
<Query><Where><BeginsWith><FieldRef Name="FileLeafRef"/><Value Type="File">{MyCustomParameter}</Value></BeginsWith></Where></Query>
```

If i use classic experience everything works fine, but if i switch the library to new experience (ModernUI), the filter not apply and no documents are shown.
Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Doesn't seem to available (2018 feb) and has been declined for Modern UI according to this [uservoice](https://sharepoint.uservoice.com/forums/601165-suggestion-archive/suggestions/17060884-modern-page-list-view-url-parameters-not-availabl).